# Character moves slow when parented to moving platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D platformer game in Unity. My character moves by applying velocity to the rigid body and works just as I want it to for precise controls.

When the character is on a moving platform, I parent the character to the moving platform so that the character stays on while the platform moves. Here's the code that's on the moving platform

```
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(transform);
        }
    }
    
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }
```

I'm also using transform.position from one position to another to move the platform.

Here's the issue. The character works perfectly fine only if the speed of the platform is 0. If the platform is moving at all, the character will move like a slug while walking on the platform. Any ideas on how to fix the issue or is there a way to have the character ride on the moving platform without parenting it to it?

Edit: I forgot to include this earlier. I've tested to see if the physics materials would make a difference. I included a 0 friction physics material on the character, the platform, and both at the same time. None of the combinations made any difference. The player still move sluggish while the platform is moving.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving your character with a force and a rigidbody, the hierarchy and who is the parent is not going to have much influence as the movement is provided by the force, this is with the physics.
If you where manipulating the transform in the code for the movement that would be important, but if movement is produced by forces I think its not.
I would check the frictions of the  Physic Materials of the player and the platform in order to define the movement of the elements respect each other.

Comment: I forgot to mentioned, I have tried adding 0 friction physics materials to both the player character as well as the platform. This didn't alter anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a while for the answer but I think I found one. Moving the platform in `FixedUpdate` rather than in `Update` can fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try setting RigidBody2D Interpolate on the player object to Extrapolate worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).